# Recording data using microphone for a fixed duration

Tags: android, audio, microphone, recording

I would like to know if there is a way to fix the duration of recording using mobile's microphone. Like when I click a button the recording should start and it should stop after 5 seconds on its own, what method do you propose me to use :-)

Edit:

Sorry for the confusion but I am using AudioRecorder class to record data and I don't think the MediaRecorder class function works properly (/at all) for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use a timer, I do not think that you can accurately control how much data is within the buffer when your app reads it.

I think they way to record 5 seconds of audio data is to use the technique from [this class](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/audio/record/AudioClipRecorder.java).

The code there carefully sets the size of the audio buffer so that it will call back after it has recorded data for a certain amount of time. Here is a snipped from that class.

```
public boolean startRecordingForTime(int millisecondsPerAudioClip,
            int sampleRate, int encoding)
    {
        float percentOfASecond = (float) millisecondsPerAudioClip / 1000.0f;
        int numSamplesRequired = (int) ((float) sampleRate * percentOfASecond);
        int bufferSize =
                determineCalculatedBufferSize(sampleRate, encoding,
                        numSamplesRequired);

        return doRecording(sampleRate, encoding, bufferSize,
                numSamplesRequired, DEFAULT_BUFFER_INCREASE_FACTOR);
    }
```

Then later on your code just does this:

```
while (continueRecording)
        {
            int bufferResult = recorder.read(readBuffer, 0, readBufferSize);
//do stuff
        }
```

since readBufferSize is just right, you will get the amount of data you want (with some slight variation)

Comment: awesome answer ... thanks I am sure this information will be of great help :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is all what you need.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.Record)
        {
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            mediaRecorder.stop();
                            mediaRecorder.reset();
                            mediaRecorder.release();
                            files.setEnabled(true);
                            record.setEnabled(true);
                            stop.setEnabled(false);

                        }
                    });

                }
            }, 5000);

            record.setEnabled(false);
            files.setEnabled(false);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            try
            {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "" + new Random().nextInt(50) + ".3gp");
                adapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder
                        .setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mediaRecorder
                        .setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.start();
                stop.setEnabled(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setMaxDuration` from MediaRecorder class.

alternately

When you start recording start a new thread and put it to sleep for 5 seconds. when it wakes stop the recording. 
or use a timertask which shall call the stop recording after 5 second delay. 
or