# Auto stop recording after seconds

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new in Android Development with no big knowledge around Java. I know how to record sound with start/stop buttons and I also know how to record audio with long press on button, but I want it to auto stop after 10 seconds.
I have read older post in here but I can not add the missing code, like the one from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930853/recording-data-using-microphone-for-a-fixed-duration) or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991196/record-voice-for-a-specific-time-period-in-android).

If someone can help post almost all the code after import stuff, since I am not good in Java yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should store the recorder in a class level variable, then create a handler to stop it in 10 seconds:

```
  Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
      }
    }, 100);
```

(BTW, You should post your code)